# Invalid hook call when trying to call child component from select change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, formik

I'm working on an app for the org I do volunteer work for and am building a patient app using `NextJS`, `Tailwind`, `Formik` and `Yup`, amongst other things.

I'm currently working on a registration form and am running into this `invalid hook` call when I select a field from a select list.

My goal is to maximise re-usability as I will ultimately be building a dozen or so forms, I have tried to create child components on areas where I know I will re-use.

I'm sure I'm doing this component/childComponent wrong, so am looking for a bit of guidance to help me out.

**Child Component I am calling, `GetDistrictsAPI`**

```js
import useSWR from "swr";
import axios from "axios";

export function GetDistrictsAPI(provID) {
  
  let query;
  provID ? query = `?province_id=${provID}` : query = ''
  
  const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/districts${query}`, fetcher);
  
  return [data]
}
```

**The function I'm using as the `onChange` event in my Formik `Field as Select`**

```js
export function RegForm() {
.... // code above
  function useProvinces(pr){
    
    let chosenProvince = pr;
    [ districts ] = GetDistrictsAPI(chosenProvince);
    console.log(chosenProvince);
  }
.... // code below
```

And the JSX code rendering my Provinces select field, which I want to trigger the onChange event from

```js
<Field
  as="select"
  id="pxProvince"
  name="pxProvince"
  onChange={useProvinces}
  className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
>
  {!provinces ? provinces : provinces.map((p, i) => (
     <option key={i} value={p.prov_id}>{p.prov_name}</option>
  ))}
</Field>
```

If interested in seeing the full code, you can view the `rego.jsx` file [here](https://github.com/TimLavelle/cv-patient-platform/blob/main/src/components/forms/rego.jsx)
Any insights, ideas, or `you're doing it all wrong, look into this instead`, is completely appreciated! :)

Comment: Your `GetDistrictsAPI` function is a custom React hook, you cannot nest it inside another (non-hook) function. You should call `GetDistrictsAPI` at the top level of the `RegForm` component, or make the `useProvinces` function an actual React hook too.

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves, those are some good areas for me to investigate! I will look into that. 

Appreciate it mate!

Comment: Thanks again mate, I've created a custom hook and I can now get it all working as expected. A few small things to fix, but I can get that going. Appreciate it!